# What integer values make p^2+10pq+q^2 a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The smallest positive integers which make $ p^2+10pq+q^2$ a perfect square are p=1, q=2.
Is there an algorithm yielding larger values (if any)? Is there a way of determining how many solutions there are?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: By algebraic symmetry, every scaling of (1,2) is a solution. The same is true of any consecutive pair which gives a solution for $p^2+2kpq+q^2$.

Comment: (5,6) is also a solution in the original case. All I need in the general case is for $2(k+1)p(p+1)$ to be 8 X a triangular number.

Comment: How about editing that into your post, as well as reading the other post.

Comment: Sorry, the post quoted answers my question. My post withdrawn.